# Nested Horizontal view inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want Horizontal scrollable items in vertical recyclerView. horizontal items will not be more than 10 in any case.

I thought of two approaches 
1) Horizontal Recyclerview as item in vertical RecyclerView 
2) Custom horizontalScrollView as an item in vertical RecyclerView

I have implemented first one facing some issues in scrolling but I think I will manage that.

My question is, why not second approach. I have seen all related question on SO and most of them trying to do with first approach. Why is it so?

What is disadvantage? specially I you have limited number in horizontal view.

Any pointer would be great help.

Answer (score 1):

**Why do we use RecyclerView instead of LinearLayout?**

Because if we use a LinearLayout consisting of (let's say 50 items) they will be all rendered on screen (50 Views) and this will lead to very very bad performance issues and scalability issues. RecyclerView does initialize the views that appears on screen only ,let's say 7 views, and they will be recycled in every new row that comes.

**Why do we use Horizontal Recyclerview instead of Horizontal ScrollView?**

This is not usually the case. If you have multiple items in every row that needs to be recycled then you should use Horizontal RecyclerView otherwise it won't matter at all.

To summarize,

The views in the vertical RecyclerView will got recycled whether it has another horizonal RecyclerView or Horizontal ScrollView, but the views inside the Horizontal ScrollView will not get recycled and the views inside the Horizontal RecyclerView will got recycled as it's a RecyclerView.

If you don't have multiple items in your Horizontal RecyclerView, you shall use Horizontal ScrollView instead.

Comment: But if we implement CustomView as HorizontalScroller we will still have that advantage because vertical recyclerView will recycle that view too. right?